# the appropriate records won't update with condition

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am completely new in mongodb. I have a collection with these reocrds in it.

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.Users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("618ac9c1b2bd7211de8dea73"), "username" : "user1", "favorites" : { "countries" : [ "Germany", "Tibet" ], "language" : [ "english", "germany", "italian" ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("618aca52b2bd7211de8dea74"), "username" : "user2", "favorites" : { "language" : [ "english", "germany" ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("618aca78b2bd7211de8dea75"), "username" : "user3" }
```

suppose I want to add a value for all records with follwoing condition

```
 db.Users.update({"favorites.language":"english"},{$addToSet:{"favorites.language":"french"}})
```

but it just updates the record for user1. but user2 has also  {"favorites.language":"english"}  . But it does not update.
can any one help me for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add multi:true to be able to update all records as follow:

```
db.Users.update({"favorites.language":"english"},{$addToSet:{"favorites.language":"french"}},{multi:true})
```